# Unable to create Foreign Key references to Primary Key with Auto Increment and Prefix

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, foreign-keys, primary-key, auto-increment

I'm quite new to SQL. I have a problem here, I cannot create a foreign key references to the primary key which is auto increment with prefix (`S0001,S0002` and so on).

This is my SQL query

```
CREATE TABLE Staff
(
   No int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
   Staff_ID AS 'S' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(No as varchar(10)), 3) PERSISTED,

   CONSTRAINT PK_Staff PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Staff_ID),

   Staff_Name varchar(30),
   Staff_Username varchar(30),
   Staff_Password varchar(30),
   Staff_Email varchar(30),
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Manager
(
   No int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
   Staff_ID AS 'S' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(No as varchar(10)),3),

   CONSTRAINT FK_Staff_ID FOREIGN KEY (Staff_ID) REFERENCES Staff(Staff_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,

   Manager_Name varchar (30),
   Manager_Email varchar (30),
);
```

As you can see, I have created 2 tables `Staff` and `Manager`, I wanted to create a foreign key in `Manager` referencing the `Staff.Staff_ID`. But end up it returns me with this error message:

> Msg 1764, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Computed Column 'Staff_ID' in table 'Manager' is invalid for use in 'FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT' because it is not persisted.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

I had already tried adding `PERSISTED` into the `Manager` query and it able to create a `Manager` table but when I manually key in the value, it returns me an error message.

```
CREATE TABLE Manager
(
    No int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
    Staff_ID AS 'S' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(No as varchar(10)),3) PERSISTED,

    CONSTRAINT FK_Staff_ID FOREIGN KEY (Staff_ID) REFERENCES Staff(Staff_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,

    Manager_Name varchar (30),
    Manager_Email varchar (30),
);
```

Manually inserting value

```
INSERT INTO Manager (Staff_ID,Manager_Name,Manager_Email)
VALUES ('S002','Kelvin','scammerforever@gmail.com')
```

and error message came out.

> Msg 271, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The column "Staff_ID" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator.

Any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Why do you need to reference the **computed** column? Why don't you just add a reference to the `IDENTITY` column `no` .....

Comment: Since `Staff_ID` is a **computed** column, of course, you **CANNOT** insert explicit values into it! You need to insert a value into `no` (or let the `IDENTITY` mechanism do its work) and the `Staff_ID` value will be **automatically** set for you

Comment: Adding the `PERSISTED` to the `Manager.Staff_ID` column makes this work just fine on SQL Server 2012......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't insert a value for the calculated field. Insert without it to use the next identity:

```
INSERT INTO Manager (Manager_Name, Manager_Email)
VALUES ('Kelvin', 'scammerforever@gmail.com')
```

If you want to specify the field, you would specify the value that it's based on, i.e. the identity field. You can use the [`identity_insert` setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) to override the identity:

```
set identity_insert Manager on

INSERT INTO Manager (No, Manager_Name, Manager_Email)
VALUES (2, 'Kelvin', 'scammerforever@gmail.com')

set identity_insert Manager off
```

Comment: Yes, I know that we can't insert value into the computed column. Example: I added `INSERT INTO Staff (Staff_Name, Staff_Username, Staff_Password, Staff_Email)
VALUES ('Kelvin', 'kelvin123','abc123', 'scammerforever@gmail.com')` Since the Staff_ID is auto increment so by right the ID is S001. But if I follow your way without adding **Staff_ID** in the **Manager** table, means it will generate a new **Staff_ID** for Kelvin, instead of following the original **Staff_ID** from the **Staff** Table which is S001.

Comment: @ChuahChengJun: The `Manager` table doesn't consider the id from the `Staff` table to be an original, it has its own `No` and `Staff_ID` fields that are not dependant on the fields in the `Staff` table. If you want the `No` field in the `Manager` table to be the same as for a record in the `Staff` table you have to override the identity and insert a specific value. However, in that case I think that you should reconsider having primary keys that loosely matches between the tables, and perhaps use a regular foreign key instead.

Comment: Ok thanks to you guys. I just figured it out and it is working as what I'm expecting for. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to specify the computed column in insert statement

Try this

```
INSERT INTO Manager (Manager_Name,Manager_Email)
VALUES ('Kelvin','scammerforever@gmail.com')
```

It will automatically compute and insert value into staff_Id